# Multithreads: lock on get and set

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I know that in a program that works with multiple threads it's necessary to synchronize the methods because it's possible to have problems like race conditions.
But I cannot understand why we need to synchronize also the methods that need just to read a shared variable. 
Look at this example:

```
public ConcurrentIntegerArray(final int size) { 
    arr = new int[size]; 
} 

public void set(final int index, final int value) { 
    lock.lock(); 
    try { 
        arr[index] = value; 
    } finally { 
        lock.unlock(); 
    } 
} 

public int get(final int index) { 
    lock.lock(); 
    try { 
        return arr[index]; 
    } finally { 
        lock.unlock(); 
    } 
}
```

They did a look on the get and also on the set method.
 On the set method I understand why. For example if I want to put with Thread1 in index=3 the number 5 and after some milliseconds the Thread2 have to put in index=3 the number 6. 
Can it happen that I have in index=3 in my array still a 5 instead of a 6 (if I don't do a synchronization on the method set)?
 This because the Thread1 can have a switch-context and so the Thread2 enter in the same method put the value and after the Thread1 assign the value 5 on the same position So instead of a 6 I have a 5.
But I don't understand why we need (look the example) to synchronize also the method get.
 I'm asking this question because we need just to read on the memory and not to write.
So why we need also on the method get to have a synchronization? Can someone give to me a very simple example?

Comment: Please also see [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods need to be synchronized.  Without synchronization on the `get` method, this sequence is possible:

1. `get` is called, but the old value isn't returned yet.
2. Another thread calls `set` and updates the value.
3. The first thread that called `get` now examines the now-returned value and sees what is now an outdated value.

Synchronization would disallow this scenario by guaranteeing that another thread can't just call `set` and invalidate the `get` value before it even returns.  It would force a thread that calls `set` to wait for the thread that calls `get` to finish.

Comment: You seem to be saying that locking prevents a kind of interleave where a set call can complete between where get reads the value and returns. This doesn't really seem like a good reason because that can technically still happen with the lock.

Comment: @Radiodef The lock will prevent the `set` method from changing the value while the `get` method retrieves it.  Once `get` has returned the value and given up the lock, then of course it's fine, and expected, for `set` to change the value.

Comment: if i understand you mean that if i don't put the lock also on the set method, i can "lost" some information? example: in the array in index 3 i have a 5, i call get method to get this value(5) but another thread before to read this value... entered in the set method and on index 3 putted a 10... so after by the get method i have back a 10 instead of a 5... my interpretation is right?

Comment: You can return out-of-date info if there isn't a lock in `get`.  If index 3 has a `5`, then the get method is called, the value is retrieved, but it doesn't have a chance to return the value.  The `set` is called and it sets the value at that index to `10`.  Then the `get` method returns an outdated value, the `5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not lock in the get method than a thread might keep a local copy of the array and never refreshes from the main memory. So its possible that a get never sees a value which was updated by a set method. Lock will force the visibility.

Comment: what do you mean with: visibility?

Answer (score 0):

Each thread maintain their own copy of value. The synchronized ensures that the coherency is maintained between different threads. Without synchronized, one can never be sure if any one has modified it. Alternatively, one can define the variable as volatile and it will have the same memory effects as synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The locking action also guarantees memory visibility. From the [Lock doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> All **Lock** implementations *must* enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, [...]:
>
> - A successful **lock** operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful *Lock* action.
> - A successful **unlock** operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful *Unlock* action.

Without acquiring the lock, due to [memory consistency errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html), there's no reason a call to `get` needs to see the most updated value. Modern processors are very fast, access to DRAM is comparatively very slow, so processors store values they are working on in a local cache. In concurrent programming this means one thread might write to a variable in memory but a subsequent read from a different thread gets a stale value because it is read from the cache.

The locking guarantees that the value is actually read from memory and not from the cache.